# Spring JAR files not present in new Eclipse Spring project

Tags: eclipse, spring, jar

I installed Spring in Eclipse/EE simply from the Eclipse Marketplace. 
However, either the Spring jar files aren't there, or am missing something within the project setup.

I looked to find them in the project library thru "Build path". I even tried searching the .jar files within the Windows directories.

I know I'm missing something big-- please bear with me.

Took me hours.

Note: I saw stackoverflow.com/questions/6288563/adding-external-jar-file-in-eclipse/11004869.

Update: found the jars in an earlier release-- 3.05. OK now i think.

Comment: First few chapters of http://javabrains.koushik.org/p/spring-framework.html should help you get started with a Spring project. Same for any spring video on youtube by SpringSource guys.

Answer (score 0):

Of course they are not there. There is not reason for them to be in eclipse. Select File > New > Spring Template project. This will create new maven project with spring dependencies included

Comment: The one i created was a "Spring Project"-- one of the four listed on the Dashboard. What then is "Spring Project" for? What if I want to use Spring's BeanFactory in a Java prj? saw in in a tutorial. Where can i get and import those jars??

Comment: That kind of project is not based on maven, always use maven or you will spend a lot of hours with searching for dependencies. Maven search for dependencies for you. Make sure to learn maven before you start codings.

Comment: so, what more am i supposed to do to configure it? there are several "Mavel integrations for Eclipse"

Comment: STS is installed, it was there when i've ran into this.

Comment: something else must be missing. not even the basic .jars not being there is a bit odd.

Comment: @vishal.biyani thx for the fine link. those were the videos i was on &very fine ones. ch4 is the one calling for Spring packages & where i'm stuck.

Comment: btw, you dont need all the trouble if youre using maven just for this. the spring .jars turned out to be right there as i soon found out as a new beginner. they simply aren't "in the package" during installation.